# creating shiroFilter faild

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, shiro

When I added ***Shiro*** to my project, it encounters a problem that said **creating shiroFilter failed**.

The following is my error log.

```
严重: Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'securityManager' while setting bean property 'securityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myShiroRealm' while setting bean property 'realm'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myShiroRealm': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'realmService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ccu.springDataDao.system.UserInfoRepo ccu.service.RealmServiceImpl.userInfoRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ccu.springDataDao.system.UserInfoRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myShiroRealm' while setting bean property 'realm'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myShiroRealm': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'realmService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ccu.springDataDao.system.UserInfoRepo ccu.service.RealmServiceImpl.userInfoRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ccu.springDataDao.system.UserInfoRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
 ... 24 more
```

---

And this is Shiro setup:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>        
    <property name="filters">
        <map><entry key="authc" value-ref="formAuthenticationFilter"/></map>
    </property> 
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions"> 
        <value>  
            /LoginCtr/**=anon
            /areaMessagectr/**=authc 
            /checkcepairplanctr/**=authc
            /acceptancectr/**=authc
            /schedulectr/**=authc
            /maintenance/**=authc
            /maintenanceapplicationctr/**=authc
            /postmaintenanceplanctr/**=authc
        </value> 
    </property> 
 </bean>
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your spring setup, can you share it?

Comment: @Wouter I **edit** it. And you can see the that in the **question**.  Thinks for you look that.

Comment: Please add the complete spring config nicely formatted

Comment: The error says "No qualifying bean of type [ccu.springDataDao.system.UserInfoRepo] " so that means there is something wrong with your spring config, not the shiro part, so you need to post you whole spring config for us to be albe to help